# Remove divs for each sentence inside paragraph

Tags: php, jquery, html, editor, nicedit

I had used nicEdit for edit my paragraphs and questions etc.With some alignments too.

[image]

In the above I had showed you one example. This is single paragraph only. However in the rich text editor by default it will enclose each sentence with a `<div>`. For one drag and drop issue. I had added css code with

```
.nicEdit-main div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So that I can drag and drop boxes.Now what is the issue because of my addition of `inline-block`. If people will try to delete or move forward backwards instead of moving words it's deleting content. What is the solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

http://www.nicedit.com/demos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to remove all divs without class attr inside the element `.nicEdit-main`

```
   $('.nicEdit-main div:not([class])').each(function(){
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    });
```